# I've known her since I've lived in this street

Tags: grammar

Both sentences in the following pairs are correct, but there is a difference in the meanings which I'm not quite certain to grasp. My guess is that in the first sentence the clause after *since* signifies a moment in the past, while in the second one a period of time up to now is meant.
Would somebody be willing to help me?

**I've known her since we were at school together.
I've known her since I've lived in this street.**

**We visit my parents every week since we bought the car.
We visit my parents every week since we've had the car.**

Comment: @cobaltduck    No. It's standard British English.

Comment: When I hear “lived in this street” I think: “homeless guy with a box.”

Comment: This all depends on your usage of “since”. Do you mean “***because*** I’ve lived on this street I’ve known her.  Or do you mean “***starting from the time*** that I lived on this street.

Comment: @Jim And when *I* hear "lived *on* this street", I think of a homeless guy with a box: British & American usage are different!

Comment: @cobaltduck No! It's English as spoken by the English!

Comment: AmE: "I've known her since I __moved__ to this street", "I've known her __ever__ since I've __been__ liv __ing__ __on__ this street" "I've known her __ever__ since I've lived __on__ this street"

Comment: @Mitch     It's OK, but what is the difference in the meanings? Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: @Jim     No, it does NOT mean "because" in these sentences. It has to do with a point or period of time.

Answer (score -2):

Since should be used when we denote a given point of time in the past. '... since we were at school...' is okay.

'I have lived' does not refer to any given point of time in the past. 'Since I started to live' would refer to a specific beginning.

On the same lines, saying 'since we bought the car' is okay; 'since we have had the car' is not correct.

See https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-m_for-since.htm if necessary.

Comment: Why is "'since we have had the car' is not correct."? (I think it's fine.) You need to **explain** your answers - not just make claims about was is & is not correct without any explanation.

Comment: Both "since we were at school together" and "since I've lived in this street" have a specific starting point in time (when he/they started school; when he moved into that street). Why say that it has to be "Since I *started* to live in this street", but not "Since we *started* at school together" - how it one different from the other?

Comment: @TrevorD The difference is that if you take away _since_ (which isn't integral to the clause), “we were at school” is past, while “I've lived in this street” is present (perfect). As such, the sentence falls foul of the ‘rule’ that the clause following _since_ must refer to a point in the past—but that's a bogus ‘rule’ anyway. The ‘rule’ is to blame, not the sentence.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Noted. But you seem effectively to be saying taht as the 'rule' is bogus, it doesn't matter anyway?  Hence both are OK? My point was that KSV states "Since should be used when we denote *a given point of time in the past*" - but "we were at school together" doesn't denote a *point* of time in the past: only a period of time. OTOH, "Since I've lived in this street" *does* imply a specific point of time in the past, namely when I first moved into this street.

Comment: @TrevorD Yes, the rule is bogus. Or rather, it's not bogus to say that _since_ requires the listener to be able to extrapolate a point (or period) in time that is in the past; but the dependent clause that _since_ heads doesn't have to be in the past tense—it can be present perfect as well, or even plain present (cue Axl Rose screa--singing “I don't have anything // Since I don't have you”).

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet     No, "Since I don't have you” means "because I don't have you", but there is no such a meaning in the sentences. BTW they are from Michael Swan's Practical English Usage, but he does not elaborate on the difference of meaning: "Since can be used as a conjunction of time, introducing its own clause. The
tense in the since-clause can be perfect or past, depending on the meaning."

Comment: @MvLog No, in the song quoted, it means “ever since I don't have you”.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet      Then it's ungrammatical. It's OK in song lyrics but rather be avoided in daily speaking/writing.

Comment: @MvLog No, it's not ungrammatical. It's perfectly fine and it is used in normal speech by native speakers, especially in AmE. Swan’s ‘rule’ is simplified and bogus (as is so often the case with grammar and usage books for non-native speakers). What is ungrammatical is “there is no such a meaning” and “it's OK… but rather be”.